# What does it mean for a random number generator's sequence to be only 1-dimensionally equidistributed?

Tags: randomness, statistics, pseudo-random-generators

Whilst reading up on [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) I came across the following (emphases added):

> The following xorshift+ generator, instead, has 128 bits of state, a maximal period of 2^128 − 1 and passes BigCrush:
>
> `[snip code]`
>
> This generator is one of the fastest generator passing BigCrush; however, **it is only 1-dimensionally equidistributed**.

Earlier in the article there's the following:

> `[snip code]`
>
> Both generators, as all xorshift* generators of maximal period, emit a sequence of 64-bit values **that is equidistributed in the maximum possible dimension**.

What does it mean for a sequence to be equidistributed in one dimension vs. multiple dimensions vs. not at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This website](http://xorshift.di.unimi.it/) provides the answer:

> A `xorshift*` generator with an n-bit state space is $n/64$-dimensionally equidistributed: every $n/64$-tuple of consecutive 64-bit values appears exactly once in the output, except for the zero tuple (and this is the best possible for 64-bit values). A `xorshift+` generator is however only $(n/64 − 1)$-dimensionally equidistributed: every $(n/64 − 1)$-tuple of consecutive 64-bit values appears exactly $2^{64}$ times in the output, except for a missing zero tuple.

In the case of a `xorshift+` which uses 128 bits of state, `n/64 - 1 = 128/64 - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1`, so the Wikipedia article was correct in stating that that particular generator is only 1-dimensionally equidistributed.

Comment: Wasn't there a famous example with a PRNG by Intel that was used in the wild which had structure already in triples? There are nice pictures of that phenomenon that could help illustrate the problem.